# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: InternetExplorerDriverService

Tags: selenium-grid

public WebDriver launchTargetUrl(String moduleName) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    DesiredCapabilities cap = null;
    System.out.println(moduleName);
    try {

```
    // *************** Selenium Grid Setup***************// 
     String nodeUrl; if(moduleName.equals("Transactions")) 
     { 
     nodeUrl = "http://10.xx.xxx.xx:5555/wd/hub"; 
     } 
     else { 
    nodeUrl ="http://10.xx.xxx.xx:5557/wd/hub"; 
    } 
     cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
     cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM,Platform.WINDOWS );

    // *************** Selenium Grid Setup Ends***************//
    //System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "./IEDriverServer.exe");
    //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./chromedriver.exe");
    // Enable the below line if you are not running as Selenium Grid
    //driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    //driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), cap);
    driver.get(targeturl);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(15000);
    return driver;
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    return null;
}
```

}

Running below command to register the node and it is getting registered successfully.

C:>java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="C:\IEDriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone
-3.7.1.jar -role node -hub http://10.xx.xxx.xxx:443/grid/register -port 5555 -b
rowser  "browserName=internetexplorer"

When I run for Suite for IE getting following error

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: InternetExplorerDriverService
```

The same code is working fine for chrome